# Blocks not showing on front page, but they don't have any page/content restrictions

Tags: 7, blocks

I do maintenance on a drupal site and between my last maintenance and this one someone changed -something- in the configuration which is causing the front page to not have a sidebar. The behavior is the same for anon users and admin users.

If I click on any of the other Pages or Articles, all the blocks in the sidebar show up again. I've checked their configurations in the Blocks Admin page, but neither of the blocks have any kind of restriction on pages or content type:

[image]

I've checked that the default theme doesn't set a different front page, so it should be using the default feed.

[image]

I've also checked if Views was used to replace the front page, but the Front Page View is not enabled:

[image]

I've looked through all of the settings in the default theme (MAYO) and I don't see anything that would prevent the sidebar or the blocks from showing up.

What else could be causing the front page not to have a sidebar?

Comment: I am guessing that the page.tpl.php is wrapping sidebar regions with `if !$is_front` and/or equivalent logic is doing it in the template.php of that theme.

Comment: Also check if a page--front.tpl.php was added.